Authentication options with Google Translate v3 Advanced REST API without using ADC for Salesforce
I am working on an integration between Salesforce and Google Translate and want to use the Advanced V3 API. It seems however that there is no way of authenticating to the APIs without having access to a command line based on https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/rest
My understanding is:

I can't use an API key for v3 advanced
I can use ADC because I need to put the credentials in an environment variable which I don't have access to
I can't use gcloud credentials as they require the system to have command line access

Anyone managed to get the API connected from a platform with similar restrictions and no official library?
Update:
Salesforce allows HTTP callouts and parameters can be set in the header or body. Typically requests use OAuth, API keys, JWT tokens or another standard setup.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
It would be helpful if you can also describe what options or interface you have on the Salesforce side for implementing the integration

Hey, on Salesforce we can make HTTP callouts and put parameters in the header or body of the request like you can with a cURL based command. The standard ways of authenticating are OAuth, api keys or JWT tokens etc. Will add to the question.
